# format authors in .bst file for bib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, revtex

I wanna that when there are more than three authors in .bib file, latex can truncate authors automatically.

Say `Tang, J. and Scellato, S. and Musolesi, M. and Mascolo, C. and Latora, V.` in .bib file should display in paper as `Tang, J., Scellato, S. and Musolesi, M. et al.`

**Expected Format** first author **,** second author **and** third author **et al.**

I get apsrev4-1.bst. Solutions for truncating author [when there are 5 or more authors](https://journals.aps.org/revtex/revtex-faq#b9).

> How do I get a truncated reference, e.g., "Ann Author et al." when there are 5 or more authors?
>
> The BibTeX style files distributed with REVTeX 4.1 no longer truncate the author lists of references (REVTeX 4's .bst files would truncate the list if there were more than 10 authors). APS editors prefer full author lists be used for references with 15 or less authors. For longer lists, use the phrase "and others" in place of the authors you want to omit.

But it need add "and others" in .bib file. How to automatically format authors without modify .bib file as I expected format?

```
@Article{2010Tang.J,
  Title                    = {Small-world behavior in time-varying graphs},
  Author                   = {Tang, J. and Scellato, S. and Musolesi, M. and Mascolo, C. and Latora, V.},
  Journal                  = {Phys. Rev. E},
  Year                     = {2010},

  Month                    = {May},
  Pages                    = {055101},
  Volume                   = {81},

  Doi                      = {10.1103/PhysRevE.81.055101},
  File                     = {:..\\pdfs\\Small-worldbehaviorintime-varyinggraphs\\Small-worldbehaviorintime-varyinggraphs.pdf:PDF},
  Issue                    = {5},
  Numpages                 = {4},
  Publisher                = {American Physical Society},
  Url                      = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevE.81.055101}
}
```

The `format.names` in apsrev4-1.bst

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ { pop$ "" } {
    duplicate$ num.names$
    duplicate$ 'numnames :=
    'namesleft :=
    's :=
    #1 'nameptr :=
    ""
      { namesleft #0 > }
      {
      format.names.morfont
        bibinfo bibinfo.check
        type$ "presentation" =
          'check.speaker
          'skip$
        if$
        't :=
        nameptr #1 > not
          {
            t *
          } {
            namesleft #1 >
              {
                names.punctuate
                t *
              } {
                s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                  { 't := }
                  { pop$ }
                if$
                numnames #2 >
                  'names.punctuate
                  'skip$
                if$
                t "others" =
                  {
                    " " *
                    bbl.etal
                    emphasize
                    *
                  } {
                    bbl.and
                    space.word *
                    t *
                  }
                if$
              }
            if$
          }
        if$
        nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
        namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
      }
    while$
  } if$
}
```

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex`? You'd  just have to set an option.

Comment: Can I just modify .bst file? Any references about the grammer of .bst file? I just don't know what is the scope of `if$`.

Comment: .bst file looks like organized by a language. There seems be a flow control and variables.

Comment: Reverse polish notation. `biblatex`  is much much easier to customize. In you case by giving the option `maxnames=3` to truncate after a maximum of three authors.

Comment: Grammar of .bst file. Doc [tame the beast](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)